# Перестановка столбцов в таблице

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые, форумчанине! Делаю на javascript перестановку столбцов таблицы, но этот [код](http://jsfiddle.net/Pc4me/12/)
не хочет работать. Как важное условие здесь, нельзя никак редактировать структуру html, в том числе дописывать к ячейке таблицы или ей самой никакие id и name. Все обозначены как class=t1. Задача с помощью функции самописной переставлять значения столбцов. Подскажите верное направление или на ошибку укажите, потому что javascript знаю лишь основы и недавно. Буду благодарен за конструктивный ответ.

Comment: Ну я же указал ссылку на пример кода, там понятно думаю из кода, есть кнопка и таблица. Функция inversion(2,1) делает замену 2 на 1 столбец, а 1-й на 2-й, с учетом того что отсчет с нуля идет. Вызывается она по событию onclick на button'е.

Comment: в ie смотрите? swapNode есть только там.

Comment: Вообще сказали чтобы во всех браузерах пахал код, в ie тоже. Я думал это будет работать везде...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно наверное как-то так поправить:

```
function inversion(first_column, second_column){
    var mytable1 = document.getElementsByClassName("t1")[0];
    if (mytable1 && mytable1.tagName != "TABLE") {
        alert("Таблица не найдена!");
        return;
    }

    var tempvar = '';

    alert("Цикл начался!");

    for (var i=0; i<mytable1.rows.length; i++)
    { 
      var temp = mytable1.rows[i].cells[first_column].innerHTML;
      mytable1.rows[i].cells[first_column].innerHTML = mytable1.rows[i].cells[second_column].innerHTML;
      mytable1.rows[i].cells[second_column].innerHTML = temp;        
    }     
    alert("Цикл кончился!");    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало). Я тоже сначала склонялся к переменной temp, чтобы обменять данные ячеек, но потом почему-то подумал что swapNode будет лучше. А оказалось, что нет...

Answer (score 1):

так еще можно (на больших таблицах будет ощутимо быстрее):

```
function inversion(first_column, second_column) {
    var mytable1 = document.querySelector("table.t1");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = mytable1.rows[i], i < mytable1.rows.length; i++) {
        var c1 = row.cells[first_column],
            c2 = row.cells[second_column],
            c11 = c1.cloneNode();
        row.replaceChild(c11, c2);
        row.replaceChild(c2, c1);
    };
}
```